# Web Form with Master Page keeps loading but not showing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am building a C# asp.net app, and so far, everything was ok. I have 2 master pages and they work great except when I try to load a page from a button called **'btnRegistrarse'** located in one of the master pages. Whether the page I am trying to load has content or not, it does not load.

The page starts loading but not showing, it keeps doing this in the browser:

[image]

This is the html of the Master Page:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.master.cs" Inherits="ClinicaDental.Web.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Clínica Dental &mdash; Clínica Dental</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Free HTML5 Website Template by FreeHTML5.co" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="free website templates, free html5, free template, free bootstrap, free website template, html5, css3, mobile first, responsive" />
    <meta name="author" content="FreeHTML5.co" />

    <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />

    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- Theme style  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Modernizr JS -->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="fh5co-loader"></div>

    <div id="page">
    <nav class="fh5co-nav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="fh5co-top-logo">
                <div id="fh5co-logo"><a href="#">Clínica Dental</a></div>
            </div>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="fh5co-top-menu menu-1 text-right">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>ID Usuario</a></li>
                    <li><a><asp:TextBox ID="txtCedula" runat="server" Width="116px"></asp:TextBox></a></li>
                    <li><a>Contraseña</a></li>
                    <li><a><asp:TextBox ID="txtContrasena" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="116px"></asp:TextBox></a></li>
                    <li><a><asp:Button ID="btnIngresar" runat="server" Text="Ingresar" OnClick="btnIngresar_Click" class="btn btn-primary" /></a></li>
                    <li><a><asp:Button ID="btnRegistrarse" runat="server" Text="Registrarse" OnClick="btnRegistrarse_Click" class="btn btn-primary" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the **"btnRegistrarse_Click"** code:

```
protected void btnRegistrarse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Registro.aspx");
    }
```

**EDIT**

**Registro.aspx:**

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Login.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registro.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClinicaDental.Web.Registro" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can we see your registro.aspx? The reason could be on that page instead

Comment: Did you see anything on the browser console? What's the status/response of the http call when you click on the button? you can check this on the network tab in the developer tool.

Comment: @Thangadurai the browser console shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I didn´t know what happened.

I just created a new page and used the html code from a page that was working as a template and adapted it as a I needed in the new page and it worked.